Extract third party cookies from a website using selenium python
I need to scrape all cookies including the third party ones from any website using selenium python.
The third party cookies means the cookies o other domains other than the website's domain.
I tried  .get_cookies() in selenium but it returns only first party cookies.

you can try this one.
from selenium import webdriver

data = webdriver.Chrome('path-to-chromedriver')

data.get("pass the url")

cookies_data = data.execute_script('return Cookies data from your url')

driver.quit()

for more details go on this link -->
 get data from urls or api using scraping 
